# Sync old google accout to a differnt Galaxy 6

Tags: sync, google

My phone died, and I had to get a new one.  My husband took new phone and we transferred my number to his old galaxy 6.  How do I register MY stuff on this phone so I can retrieve my photos, apps, etc.  It thinks I'm him.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sign in with your own Google account.

Having said that, unless all your photos, contacts, etc were all synced to Google, it's a bit of an unknown really exactly what will sync back to the replacement phone.